# Enable text file thumbnails in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

In Ubuntu 15.04 (new installation, no upgrade) I cannot find an option to enable thumbnails for text files. In previous Ubuntu versions the first lines of a text file can be seen.
Now in Ubuntu 15.04 all text files have the same icon. Also I cannot distinguish empty text files.

As it seems there is no option to enable thumbnails for text files any more in the settings of nautilus.

Comment: Which icon theme?

Comment: This should be it: `$ gsettings get com.canonical.unity-greeter icon-theme-name
'ubuntu-mono-dark'`